# D3.js : Set multiple attributes of SVG shape

Tags: d3.js, svg

My data array looks like this:

```
circleData = {
   "x": [10,20,30,40], "r":[1,2,3,4], "y": [0,0,0,0] 
},
{
   "x": [15,25,35,45], "r":[5,6,7,8], "y": [20,20,20,20] 
}
```

I want to create two rows of four circles with the above x, r, and y parameters. But how?  The problem is, if the x values are bound in order to create the circles, then the circles have "access" to the x data, but no longer to the r or y data.

Comment: I would restructure the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Lars Kotthoff's comment, the easiest way will probably be to restructure your data. Because D3's data binding relies on arrays, one approach would be something like this:

```
circleData = [{
   "x": [10,20,30,40], "r":[1,2,3,4], "y": [0,0,0,0] 
},
{
   "x": [15,25,35,45], "r":[5,6,7,8], "y": [20,20,20,20] 
}];

var circles = d3.merge(circleData.map(function(d) {
  return d3.zip(d.x, d.y, d.r);
}));
```

This will give you a 2-dimensional array containing 8 arrays representing all 8 circles with their `cx`, `cy`, and `r` parameters.

[image: Resulting array]

You may then bind `circles` as your data and operate very D3-*ish* on it.

```js
var circleData = [{
  "x": [10, 20, 30, 40],
  "r": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "y": [0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
  "x": [15, 25, 35, 45],
  "r": [5, 6, 7, 8],
  "y": [20, 20, 20, 20]
}];


var circles = d3.merge(circleData.map(function(d) {
  return d3.zip(d.x, d.y, d.r);
}));


var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg").append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");  // Translate for the sake of visibility

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr({
    "cx": function(d) {
      return d[0];
    },
    "cy": function(d) {
      return d[1];
    },
    "r": function(d) {
      return d[2];
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess each data object's own data needs to travel with it into whatever objects D3 creates.